# looking for a cross browser solution to highlight tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a cross browser compatible solution to highlight tabs. On page load the first tab should highlight and on click of the other tabs, the first tab would unhighlight and the selected tab would highlight. Can't get this functionality working in same fashion in IE and Firefox at the same time. Any inputs on that?

Note: The below code works but when I click on any other link on the page, the focus on the tabs is lost and hence the currently selected tab is not highlighted.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    activate('focusmeplease');
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});

function activate(link) {
    if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(link).focus();
    else if (document.all) document.all(link).focus();
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="clas" onclick="javascript: addPlayer('tab-1','1649028604001');">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="focusmeplease">First tab</a>
        </li>
        <li class="clas" onclick="javascript: addPlayer('tab-1','1651558610001');">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Second tab</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `click` event, just call the `focus` method. Like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    activate('focusmeplease');
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).focus(); //i've added this
    });
});
```

See this Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NFdah/)

Comment: Appreciate looking into this! But due to using .focus(), when I click outside of the tabs area, none of the tabs remain highlighted. I would want the last selected tab to be selected until I click on another tab.

Comment: Ah okay, then you can just use your own class and toggle it on the `a`, see this fiddle instead: http://jsfiddle.net/NFdah/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle link works perfectly fine. It works fine in Firefox on my site too, unfortunately in IE, when I click outside the tabs, the last selected tab loses focus, still trying to figure that out. I may have to look for an entirely different approach if this does not work.

Comment: Are you using your own class like I am in the fiddle instead of active? Try that

Comment: Yes I'm using my own class like you did. When I observe via IE web developer, I see that my class does not get added to the anchor link. Instead in IE my tabs highlight due to the "activate('focusmeplease')" function, so that is the reason it loses focus when I click outside. On the other hand, in FF, the class gets added to the anchor tag and it works. Strange behavior in IE. I'm wondering if the javascript:void(0) in the href of anchor tag is causing this strange behavior in IE.

Comment: It could also be due to some event capturing/bubbling issue in IE because both the li and anchor tags have a click event attached to it and only one of them executes?

Comment: Ahhh take the click event out of the `li` and leave the `a` one in!

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is the code that worked across browsers. I had to move the addPlayer function from the onClick action of the anchor tag to within the jQuery li click function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                  
                     addPlayer('tab-1', '1649028596001');//on page load, display this.
                     jQuery('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
                     jQuery('#tabs ul li').click(function () {
                              addPlayer('tab-1', playerIdArray[jQuery(this).index()]);
                              jQuery('#tabs ul li').removeClass("active");
                              jQuery(this).addClass("active");
                      });

});


<ul>

     <li class="class4" ><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bond</a></li>
     <li class="class5" ><a href="javascript:void(0);">Stock</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tab-1">

   </div>
```